# How to view ALL COLUMNS (same column names from all table) from all tables starting with Letter A?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

Is this possible? I am using ORACLE 10g.

For example: I have 50 tables name A01, A02, A03, A04.........A50.

And all these tables have the "SAME COLUMN NAME"
For example: name, age, location

**(Note: The Column Names are the same but not the value in the columns).**

In the END... I want to view all data from **column**: name, age, location FROM ALL tables starting with letter A.

**(Note 2: All tables starting with letter A are NOT STATIC, they are dynamic meaning different changes could occur. Example: A01 to A10 could be deleted and A99 Could be added).**

Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE CurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
  v_cursor    CurTyp;
  v_record    A01%ROWTYPE;
  v_stmt_str  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  for rec in (
      select table_name 
      from user_tables 
      where table_name like 'A%'
  ) loop
    if v_stmt_str is not null then
      v_stmt_str := v_stmt_str || ' union all ';
    end if;
    v_stmt_str := v_stmt_str || 'SELECT * FROM ' || rec.table_name;
  end loop;

  OPEN v_cursor FOR v_stmt_str;

  LOOP
    FETCH v_cursor INTO v_record;
    EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    -- Read values v_record.name, v_record.age, v_record.location
    -- Do something with them
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE v_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: " ... AND ALL_TABLES.DROPPED = 'NO'", perhaps.

Comment: Thanks Sir Egor, I'll review your script later... :D Thanks! I'll update you later.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding if you want to view all column names of tables starting with A then try below

```
select column_name,table_name from user_tab_cols where table_name like 'A%';
```

If your requirement is something else then specify it clearly.

Comment: Sir Aspirant, sorry for not clarifying the end output I want. Well I posted added info on my topic. By the way Sir, I don't get any output. :|

Comment: @GlennHolmgren - if you don't get any output then that means you don't have any tables starting with 'A'.  Perhaps your specification is wrong?

Comment: I do have tables with A and T, I even tried T... Maybe I did some mistake... I'll check later, thanks for the help Sir.

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correctly and the number of tables is constant then you can create a `VIEW` once

```
CREATE VIEW vw_all
AS
SELECT name, age, location FROM A01
 UNION ALL
SELECT name, age, location FROM A01
 UNION ALL
...
SELECT name, age, location FROM A50
 UNION ALL
```

And then use it

```
SELECT * 
  FROM vw_all
 WHERE age < 35
 ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Sir peterm, The tables I have on the database I am working with is not constant, its rather Dynamic, its adding from time to time... :(

Answer (score 0):

This returns you all tables you need:

```
select table_name
from user_tables
where table_name like 'A__';
```

From this, you can build a dynamic sql statement as:

```
select listagg('select * from '||table_name,' union all ') within group(order by table_name)
from user_tables
where table_name like 'A__'
```

This returns actually an SQL statement which contains all tables and the unions:

```
select * from A01 union all select * from A02 union all select * from A03
```

And finally execute this via native dynamic sql. You can do that in PL/SQL, so you need a function:

```
create function getA
    query varchar2(32000);
begin
    select listagg('select * from '||table_name,' union all ') within group(order by table_name)
    into query
    from user_tables
    where table_name like 'A__';
    open res for query;
    return res;
end;
```

Note that what you're doing manually is basically called *partitioning*, and Oracle has a super-great support already available for that out of the box. I.e. you can have something which looks like a super-huge table, but technically it is stored as a set of smaller tables (and smaller indexes), splitted by a partitioning criteria. For example, if you have millions of payment records, you may partition it by year, this way one physical table contains only a reasonable set of data. Still, you can freely select in this, and if you're hitting data from other partitions, Oracle takes care of pulling those in.